# MS CRM 2011, attributes from quotedetail to salesorderdetail

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I need to copy some custom attributes from a quotedetail (in fact also from a opportunityproduct) to a salesorderdetail when a salesorder is being created from a quote or opportunity.

How would I go about doing this?

I was in the process of writing a plugin to fire on salesorderdetail.create and then make it check the salesorder for quoteid or opportunityid and fetch either and then their lines (quotedetails or opporunityproducts).

But, as far as I know there is no unique link between say salesorderdetail and quotedetail (only between salesorder and quote/opportunity). The only thing they will have in common is the entity reference to a certain product - though this isn't unique because a quote could very well have several lines referring to the same product.

So how do I copy these custom attributes from the correct quotedetail/opportunityproduct to salesorderdetail...

Any ideas?

/Aidal

EDIT: as per the comments to Mike's answer I found the solution due to the links he provided.
The entity mapping solution seems to be the answer to the problem I was facing:

**CRM 2011/20013**: https://crm2011entitymaps.codeplex.com/releases/view/114229

**CRM 2015**: http://crm2011entitymaps.codeplex.com/

Through this solution you can find the relationships you need to edit (e.q. opportunityproduct -> quotedetail or quotedetail -> salesorderdetail) and then add field mappings for your custom attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the sequencenumber field from the opportunityproducts, quotedetail, and salesorderdetails. I would expect this number to be consistent between lines on related quotes opportunities and orders.

EDIT: I just realized that you had CRM 2011 tagged and this field is not available in CRM 2011 (I was using 2015). So this answer probably won't help you.

EDIT: The solution ended up being in the comments. So, I am adding it to the answer.

> Something you could do it create a new attribute on opportunity & quote (and order and invoice if needed) product,and assign it some sort of unique identifier when the record is created. Then create a mapping for the custom value between the product lines. That way if the other data like price, quantity, etc.. change you still have a way back to the original line.
>
> You'll also notice creating mappings for the line items isn't exposed
>   through the CRM UI, I've actually created a tool to expose these so
>   you can create the mappings. http://crm2011entitymaps.codeplex.com/

Jason Lattimer - [community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/120310](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/120310)

Comment: 2011 only has itemlinenumber I think and I don't believe it is mandatory.

Comment: Yes, I edited my post after I noticed that. My first thought was to use the line number on the quote, but from my testing I realized that the line item number seems to only be used by the connector. You could also compare both the product and quantities to make it more likely that there is a match. But, that still seems messy from a design perspective.

Comment: This post may be helpful.

http://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/120310
In his answer Jason suggests creating a mapping between the product lines using a tool that he created. (This specific mapping isn't available in the UI) 
http://crm2011entitymaps.codeplex.com/

Comment: I too thought about the product but there is nothing keeping users from making two identical lines, so that won't work either :/

Comment: I'll have a look at this mapping tool, though I would prefer if I could find a way that didn't include installing extra 3rd party solutions, if one exists. Thanks for the link though, I didn't find that one myself.

Comment: One thing to note is that you may only need to install the solution on your dev/test environment. Then the mappings can be exported to production.

Comment: Mike, I think you have given me exactly what I needed after all, thanks!